# IBM Watson Assistant: Annotations tab for creating contextual entities missing

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

I am using IBM Watson Assistant on a Lite plan in Frankfurt. I am trying to create contextual entities by annotating intents as described here:

- https://www.ibm.com/cloud/architecture/demo/try-watson-assistant-contextual-entities
- https://medium.com/ibm-watson/contextual-entities-with-ibm-watson-assistant-f41b2e0ca82e

The described Annotation Tab when creating an Entity is missing. I cannot edit Intents as described either: Doubleclicking words in the User Examples is not possible, the described Popup is not showing.

Comment: What is your chatbot language?

Comment: German. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this myself some months ago. See the [list of supported languages by feature](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-language-support). Contextual entities are not yet supported for German. Thus, you are not seeing the annotation feature.

Comment: Okay... This is somehow underwhelming. Would be an important feature in my eyes. Any idea when this is coming? Thanks a lot anyway for your help! (Cannot vote your answer up as my reputation score is too low)

Comment: I agree that it is an important feature. Right now a workaround is to have more synonyms and / or patterns and providing more training feedback. I suggest to join this public Slack workspace where developers for Watson services are around: http://wdc-slack-inviter.mybluemix.net/